# Stop long running process in webapi externally

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I am executing the action result LongRunningProcess using webclient code, anyway to stop the process execution externally rather than stopping it in iis?

```
 public IHttpActionResult LongRunningProcess()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5000000; i++)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
            return Json("Completed");
        }



 using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
                {
  string myParameters = "";
  wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
  string HtmlResult =await wc.UploadStringTaskAsync("http://...../LongRunningProcess", myParameters);
                }
```

Comment: If you don't hand off the process to outside IIS (for example into MSMQ) then you are going to have to do some magic with threads.

Comment: This might give you a glimpse of the effort required if you use threads: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/cancellation-in-managed-threads

Comment: Check if cancellationToken suits in your scenario. More info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19010856/should-we-use-cancellationtoken-with-mvc-web-api-controllers

Answer (score 0):

`LongRunningProcess` will need to cooperate to allow itself to be stopped. As an example for how to do this the following solution might be practical for you:

Make `LongRunningProcess` check a database based flag periodically. If that flag is set, exit `LongRunningProcess`. Then, you can make another action to set that flag (possibly at the press of a button).

Comment: I did it by storing value in static variable and reset that variable using another call

Comment: This will fail to work when your website becomes hosted on more than one server. If it's just one server that should be fine. @PrincePrasad

Comment: ya the request will come only from one server. so i implemented that.